# c string array dimension

Tags: c, arrays, printing

```
char pres[4][2][11] = {
    "George", "Washington",
    "John", "Adams",
    "Thomas", "Jefferson",
    "James", "Monroe"
};
```

Can someone explain why `pres` array is three dimensions? I tried display the pre array with a loop in two dimensions(`pres[4][2]`), however, it does not work.

Comment: How did you try to display it?  The array declaration/initialisation look fine...

Comment: This seems an array `[8][11]`, even if it works, you prefer `char pres[4][2][11] = {
       {"George", "Washington"},
       {"John", "Adams"},
       {"Thomas", "Jefferson"},
       {"James", "Monroe"}
    };`

Comment: Think of it as a 2-dimensional array of strings. Strings themselves are 1-dimensional arrays of characters and 2 + 1 = 3.

Comment: @KeineLust it's a valid 3D array initialisation the way it's shown as well, even without the extra braces (though they do make it clearer).

Comment: @Dmitri, you are right, edited

Comment: @Keine Lust my question is why 2 dimensions claimed as  **pres[4][2]** does not work for print out **pres** array

Comment: You have a nice answer from @JohnColeman explaining that.

Comment: So can you show how you tried to print out the array?  The array itself is fine...

Comment: Can you show your printout code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a three dimensional array of chars since it is conceptually a 2-dimensional array of strings and strings are 1-dimensional null-terminated array of characters.

While this does work, this approach has the drawback that it can only hold strings of length 10 (leaving room for the null-terminator). For this reason, it tends to be more flexible to use arrays of `char *` and then allocate and deallocate space as needed for the actual strings.

You said that you tried to look at `pres[4][2]`. That wouldn't make sense since array indexing is 0-based in C. `pres[3][1]` would be `"Monroe"` -- the last string in the array.

To print them all is very straightforward:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i;
    char pres[4][2][11] = {
        "George", "Washington",
        "John", "Adams",
        "Thomas", "Jefferson",
        "James", "Monroe"
    };
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) printf("President %s %s\n",pres[i][0],pres[i][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
President George Washington
President John Adams
President Thomas Jefferson
President James Monroe
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation .

Comment: @max Strings in C are hard to wrap your mind around if you are coming to C from a language like Python or Java that (for the most part) handles all of the complexity for you. One of the co-founders of Stack Overflow, Joel Spolsky, has written one of the best blog posts I have ever read on the subject: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: appreciate your source.

Answer (score -1):

Its because of how a string of characters is defined in C.
In C a string is just an array of single characters together, and if you want multiple words in an array you would have to give an array of arrays.

In your case you want to separate strings into separate columns, which would in for example C++ be given as an string array[][], but in C it you would have to apply another "layer" to represent the strings themselves.

Comment: "In C a string is just an array of single characters" -- The word "just" is potentially problematic since this can be read as saying that "strings" and "char arrays" are simply synonymous, which is false. It never hurts to remind a beginner about the importance of the null-terminator.